# Existing role as event target apigateway execution role

Tags: c#, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, api-gateway, aws-event-bridge

I have created an event bus where the target is an existing apigateway. everything working well except the execution role for that particular target. I am using an existing IAM role as an execution role which has both policies attached to it `"execute-api:Invoke", "execute-api:ManageConnections"`. Also assumed by `"events.amazonaws.com"`. But this is not attaching to the target as an execution role. Below is the code to use an existing role

```
 var role = Role.FromRoleName(this, roleId, roleName);

var rule = new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.CfnRule(this, ruleId, new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.CfnRuleProps
        {
            EventBusName =busName,
            Name = ruleName,
            Description = ruleDescription,
            EventPattern = eventPattern,
            State = "ENABLED",
            
            Targets = new[]
            {
                new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.CfnRule.TargetProperty
                {
                    Id = apiGatewayId,
                    Arn = apiGatewayArn,
                    InputTransformer = new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.CfnRule.InputTransformerProperty
                    {
                        InputPathsMap = inputPath,
                        InputTemplate = inputTemplate,
                    },                        
                    RoleArn = role.RoleArn,
                },                    
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`role.roleArn` is undefined because the `Role.FromRoleName` static method does not perform cloud-side lookups.  To consume an imported role's ARN, use [fromRoleArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.Role.html#static-fromwbrrolewbrarnscope-id-rolearn-options) instead.  It doesn't perform cloud-side lookups either.  It accepts a ARN, without verification.

In fact, all the CDK's various `[Something].from....Name|Arn|Attributes` static "import" methods behave the same way.   They blindly accept what you give them.  The returned constructs know what you explicitly told them.  Other properties will be undefined.

CDK [Context Methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_methods) like `Vpc.fromLookup` do actually perform synth-time "lookups" from your cloud environment and cache the results.

N.B. the `ISomething` [interface constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html#work-with-library-interfaces) returned from import methods are [read-only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_importing).

Comment: thank you, role.roleArn worked for me once I used Role.FromArn.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better served by using an SDK method to extract and find the information at Synth - if its not something that is going to change between Synth of the template and Deployment, then this is perfectly fine way to do things (and indeed, what is often done behind the scenes)

Also, I notice you're using the `Cfn` methods. These are L1 constructs - they are bare bones and do not have the necessary hook to slot into most of the `ISomething` interfaces. Events is not a new library, you shouldn't need to be using CfnRule - there should be Rule just available for you as well. Only with the L2 or L3 constructs can you make use of the handy hooks like passing the construct to another for linking the two. - you really should be using this construct instead (choose your appropriate language) : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.Rule.html

Comment: Events.Rule didn't work for me as I have to use an existin apiateway as a target where "RestApi.FromRestApiAttributes" only returns IRestApi and Events.Rule only accepts RestApi. So used CfnRule.

Comment: you can potentially (not 100% sure in this case) use the aws SDK to update the attributes as on the FromRestApi return manually before passing it into the Rule. For example, Ive  done this with dynamodb and event streams - event streams also not being retrieved with the From methods, an SDK call to retreive it and "add it" worked perfectly (of course i also did this in Python which is less restrictive than Typescript in some situations)